# Set difference of dates from different data sets R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following two dataframes,

| ID | first_date | last_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-03 |
| 2 | 2022-09-25 | 2022-09-26 |

| ID | dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-01 |
| 1 | 2022-09-02 |
| 2 | 2022-09-25 |
| 2 | 2022-09-26 |

If an ID of a first dataframe doesn't have date values within a range from first_date to last_date in second dataframe, I have to add 1 to the column named `missing` or 0 otherwise as below.

| ID | first_date | last_date | missing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-03 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-09-25 | 2022-09-26 | 0 |

How can I do this in R? Can anyone help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr`/`tidyr` way: First calculate the amount of days between the two days in `df1` and compare with the amount of days present in `df2`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 |> 
  group_by(ID) |>
    mutate(days = length(seq(from = first_date, to = last_date, by = 1))) |>
  ungroup() |>
  left_join(count(df2, ID)) |>
  mutate(missing = +!(days == n)) |>
  select(-days, -n) # You might be interested in keeping these!
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     ID first_date last_date  missing
  <dbl> <date>     <date>       <int>
1     1 2022-09-01 2022-09-03       1
2     2 2022-09-25 2022-09-26       0
```

Data:

```
library(readr)

df1 <- read_table("ID   first_date  last_date
1   2022-09-01  2022-09-03
2   2022-09-25  2022-09-26")

df2 <- read_table("ID   dates
1   2022-09-01
1   2022-09-02
2   2022-09-25
2   2022-09-26")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am using `outer` and `&` to check if any date from df2 is contained in any of the ranges specified in df1.

```r
mutate(df1, missing = (outer(first_date, df2$dates, `<`) &
                       outer(last_date, df2$dates,  `>`)) |>
                apply(1, any) |>
                as.integer())

##>   ID first_date  last_date missing
##> 1  1 2022-09-01 2022-09-03       1
##> 2  2 2022-09-25 2022-09-26       0
```

For larger problems, it would be useful to know if the ranges are disjointed or have overlaps.

You may also want to look into `?iranges::findOverlap`